# Tensorflow 1.11 needs CuDNN 7.2 for CUDA 9.0, but there is no such library

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

The [requirements](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements) of the current version of tensorflow 1.11 to run on GPU are

> - CUDA® Toolkit —TensorFlow supports CUDA 9.0.
> - cuDNN SDK (>= 7.2)

However the [CuDNN downlad page](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive) only lists

> Download cuDNN v7.2.1 (August 7, 2018), for CUDA 9.2

Given that CuDNN comes with different binaries for minor revisions of the CUDA toolkit (e.g. CuDNN 7.1.3 has one binary for CUDA 9.1 and another for CUDA 9.0), I suppose that this binary of CuDNN 7.2 is not compatible with CUDA 9.0.

Is is a documentation bug? If not, how to fullfill the requirements of TF 1.11?

Comment: I tried to install TF 1.11 with Cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.3 - the setup worked for TF 1.10, but TF 1.11 hangs on `tf.Session()`. I didn't try any other combinations though. Would be good to hear from you whether you have succeeded.

Comment: Facing the same perplexing issue. The lib kindly shared by @emilyfy works for Ubuntu & AMD CPU, but not for Windows 10 with Intel.

Answer (score 4):

I found the below answer by modifying the addresses from the publicly available libraries: https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.2.1/prod/9.0_20180806/cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.2.1.38

As @emilyfy suggested, addresses for other, hosted but not published versions and OSs can also be acquired.

Answer (score 3):

Go to this page instead. https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download

It has the link for
`Download cuDNN v7.3.0 (Sept 19, 2018), for CUDA 9.0`

Answer (score 2):

cuDNN v7.2.1 for CUDA 9.0 used to be there but now that they have v7.3.0 it's not in the archives anymore. I'm having the same problems too with a model I built on another PC. Luckily I hadn't deleted the installers. I'll share them (only the deb installers for Linux) [here](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/761495/cuDNN%20v7.2.1%20CUDA%209.0.tar.gz).

Comment: I found the folder for Win10 by guessing: https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/cudnn/secure/v7.2.1/prod/9.0_20180806/cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.2.1.38

Comment: @bugfoot that's great! Looks like it works for other OS too, simply changing any 9.2 to 9.0 in the download links for cuDNN v7.2.1 for CUDA 9.2. You should probably post this as an answer.